# Unable to Retrieve the Firebase database in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm unable to retrieve the Firebase Database. I am able to successfully upload the Data to Firebase but when I wanted to retrieve the database it shows the blank screen.

Here is the the Firebase database screenshot:

[image]

My code is:

```java
public class SubjectBooks extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseAuth fauth;
    String user;
    DatabaseReference dbreference,dbref;
    RecyclerView rv;
 String subject;
    int child_count=0;
    ArrayList<Books> list;
    SubjectBooksAdapter staggeredBooksAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_subject_books_request);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Request for Room");
     // this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
     // this.getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_share);

        fauth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        subject = getIntent().getStringExtra("subject").trim();

        dbreference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("roomrequest").child("request");
        dbreference.keepSynced(true);
        user = fauth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();

        list = new ArrayList<>();
        staggeredBooksAdapter = new SubjectBooksAdapter(list);

        rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
        rv.setAdapter(staggeredBooksAdapter);

        dbreference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                final Books b1 = dataSnapshot.getValue(Books.class);
              //  Log.e("Value is ",dataSnapshot.getKey()+" "+b1.getBauthor());
                //Log.e("Book"," received");
                if(!user.equals(b1.getSelleremail())) {
                    child_count++;
                    list.add(b1);
                    staggeredBooksAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
               // Log.e("Has child : ", dataSnapshot.getKey());
//                if(child_count==0){
//                    Toast.makeText(SubjectBooks.this, "No books found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                    Intent in = new Intent(SubjectBooks.this, BooksPage.class);
//                    startActivity(in);
//                    finish();
//                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

and code for my adapter is

```java
public class SubjectBooksAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SubjectBooksAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<Books> bookslist;
    CardView cv;
    FirebaseAuth fauth;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference dbreference;
    Books b;

    public SubjectBooksAdapter(ArrayList<Books> bookslist){
        this.bookslist = bookslist;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_request,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

   public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView bookName,bookAuthor,bookDesc,bookPrice,bookCall;
        ImageView iv;

        MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_card_view);

            iv = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            dbreference = database.getReference("roomrequest");
            bookName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookName);
            bookAuthor = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookAuthor);
            bookDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookDesc);
            bookPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookPrice);
            bookCall = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookCall);
            fauth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        dbreference = database.getReference("roomrequest");

        b = bookslist.get(position);
        holder.bookName.setText(b.getBname());
        holder.bookAuthor.setText(b.getBauthor());
        holder.bookDesc.setText(b.getBdesc());
        holder.bookPrice.setText("Rs. "+b.getPrice());
        holder.bookCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Log.e("Current user is ", fauth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());

            }
        });
        Glide.with(cv.getContext()).load(Uri.parse(b.getPics())).placeholder(R.drawable.bshelf).error(R.drawable.bshelf).into(holder.iv);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return bookslist.size();
    }
}
```

I run the code and compiled ..it compiles successfully and when when app is launched then it shows blank white screen.

If There are any other details you would like to know please comment I would be very happy to provide the details as you required.

Comment: I saw u logged data. Is data transferred to the app correctly?

Comment: @Lucefer...Thanks for reply but i solved it by commenting out this line (!user.equals(b1.getSelleremail()))

Comment: nice to here it